# How to get graphic tablet pen pressure value?

Tags: c#, api, user-input, hid, wacom

I'm using a Wacom Bamboo Pen tablet and I'd like to be able to get its pen pressure value in my application written in C#. How do I do that? Is there maybe an API that allows one to get pen values on Windows 7?

Comment: Can someone add `graphics-tablet` tag to this question?

Comment: Are you using WPF? In WPF's MouseEventArgs, there is a StylusDevice properties that can get a collection of StylusPoint. Eeach point has a PressureFactor property.

Comment: @SimonMourier I can't find it anywhere. It seems it's in `System.Windows.Input` namespace, but I don't see a reference to it in default set of components. Am I missing some software package?

Comment: It should be in PresentationCore.dll: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.input.stylusdevice.aspx

Comment: I tried using this in a WinForms app and the usual OnMouseMove handler doesn't seem to have an overload that uses PresentationCore's mouse info. I'm not sure how to make this work in a non-wpf app.

Comment: You can't. That's why I was asking about WPF.

Answer (score 15):

Wacom provides an [extensive API](http://www.wacomeng.com/windows/) to get data directly from the tablet.The API includes example code for detecting pressure, tilt and other interactions:

- [**Tilt Test**](http://www.wacomeng.com/windows/code/TiltTest.zip): Demonstrates pressure, use of the eraser and pen tilt properties
- [**Pressure Test**](http://www.wacomeng.com/windows/code/PressureTest.zip): Demonstrates how to detect and display pen pressure

These code samples are in C, but there are also examples that in c#.net that include code to handle pressure:

- **[WintabDN](http://www.wacomeng.com/windows/code/WintabDN.zip)**: Interface, scribble and tablet control samples using Wintab .NET

Using this project as an example, you can get the pressure like this:

```
// Create a data object and hook a packetlistener to receive
// updatse by the tablet
m_wtData = new CWintabData();
m_wtData.SetWTPacketEventHandler(handler);

//Handles packet receive event
void handler(object sender,MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
     //Get the packet id
     uint pktID = (uint)eventArgs_I.Message.WParam;

     //Get the data for that packet
     WintabPacket pkt = m_wtData.GetDataPacket((uint)eventArgs_I.Message.LParam, pktID);

     //Grab the pressure
     var pressure = pk.pkNormalPressure.pkAbsoluteNormalPressure;
}
```

Next, here is a [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19102/Adventures-into-Ink-API-using-WPF) that explains how to use the Wacom Tablet with the [WPF InkCanvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.inkcanvas.aspx)

A good starting point for any tablet related development on windows is also the [Ink API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms698573%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Can be a starting point

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/46281/Digitizer-interface-in-C-using-VBTablet

Thats the right link to the project: http://sourceforge.net/projects/vbtablet/