# Simulate Wacom Tablet pen pressure?

Tags: c#, wacom, pressure, stylus-pen

I've looked into the Wacom [Wintab Api](http://www.wacomeng.com/windows/) (and [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vbtablet/) wrapper) and understand how I can retrieve the pen pressure (there's also an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383203/how-to-get-graphic-tablet-pen-pressure-value) which explains how) but I can't figure out how to simulate pen pressure to send it to an application.

There are 2 use cases I want this for:

I could hold down a key to record a specific pressure level and send that fixed pressure to an application until the key is released.

I also want to record the pressure along with cursor positions to later play back into another application (I can easily send as mouse position so that's not an issue, but pen pressure..?).

To put it simply: Is there a way to write pen pressure? Or is it read-only?