# How to integrate wacom tablets to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019

I'm creating a drawing program, but I can't find a way to make my wacom tablet work with Visual Studio.

I have already tried out every event handler like StylusDown/TouchDown (which seems to work only on tablet PCs but not with Wacom). Do I need an SDK from Wacom (if so, which one)? What should my code use (like: using Wacom.Stylus / using System.Drawing)?

Comment: this could be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383203/how-to-get-graphic-tablet-pen-pressure-value

Comment: That was almost what I was searching for. But I did it doing something simpler. Gonna edit this question later and add my solution.